# writers.gdal wrong pixel size

Tags: raster, point-cloud, pdal

I want to convert the *.las* file into *.tif* by the following pipeline:

```
pipeline = [
        input_path,
        {
                "type": "writers.gdal",
                "filename": raster,
                "dimension": "Z",
                "data_type": "uint16_t",
                "output_type": "mean",
                "resolution": 1
        }
            ]
```

As a result, the metadata shows one result:

[image]

And the measurements another:

[image]

Where is the problem?

Comment: without knowing the projection of your file it's hard to say

Comment: the unknown projection for the image and EPSG:3857 for reference frame

Comment: If your image has an unknown project you can't know the pixel size

Comment: But the "CRS" field of metadata is empty

Comment: OK, but without that information each pixel might be one metre, one foot, one furlong or one light year in size,

Comment: So, I can assign manually any CRS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127507/discussion-between---and-ian-turton).